# Two PCI-E cords but only one PCI-E port on my GPU

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

So I recently bought a Gigabyte GTX 1060 GPU, and am just now putting it into my PC. However, the 1060 only has one PCI-E port. I didn't think much of this at first, but, after having turned the computer on time and time again, I noticed that the GPU itself wasn't even turning on... Is this because the one PCI-E cord isn't supplying it enough power? I'm no computer specialist, but I can see a problem when it's right in front of me... (Btw, I have a Corsair CX750M power supply) Thanks!

EDIT: When I plugged in my old GPU (an old MSI Twin FrozrII with two PCI-E ports) it worked perfectly...

Comment: If the manufacturer only put one power port on it, then that's all it needs on stock speeds/voltages. Sounds like a faulty card, or your power supply cannot provide enough power overall with that card (doubt it is this).

Answer (score 0):

As was already mentioned you only need to plug in what the card has.  Going from memory I believe nvidia uses a single connector while AMD uses 2.  If the other card works but your new one doesn't it is pretty safe to assume you have a faulty card.  If you want to be sure slave it into another pc if you have one available but I'm willing to bet a return is in order.

Comment: NVIDIA and AMD aren't limited to the number of connectors you specified. Completely depends on the card model, and the design. For example, my 980ti has 2 power connectors, while a RX 470 has one.